# Is it safe to remove entries from the registry to type libraries that no longer exist?

Tags: registry, windows-xp

Question as in title.

When I have various entries in the Registry to a type library, but the actual type library file is no longer on the system, is it safe to prune these entries from the Registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, but why would you? There's no adverse effect to leaving them be, but if you make a mistake, you could have tough to diagnose problems down the road.

In general registry "cleaning" is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Well, mainly it would be for an addition to a small utility I wrote, mostly for my own learning. I'll further consider the pros and cons of it.